# Change img size with javascript in URL

Tags: javascript, html, url

I want to change the size of an image with javascript according to the URL,

i mean that if the url is:

`mywebsite.com/something.hmtl?width=400&height=250`

the image is 400x250

and if the URL is

`mywebsite.com/something.hmtl?width=300&height=150`

the size of the image is 300x150

How can i do that with html and javascript? thanks a lot

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: You need to grab those values from the `query string`, and then pass them to your image on the page.

Comment: http://redzeronline.ucoz.com/example.html only this im a noob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get the parameters by:

```
 params = location.search.substr(1).split('&')
 dimentions = {}
 for ( i in params){
   attr = params[i].split('=')
   if(attr[0] == 'width' || attr[0] == 'height'){ 
        dimentions[attr[0]] = parseInt(attr[1] )
     }
  }
 img =  document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0] // will get you the first img of the page
 img.setAttribute('width',dimentions['width'])
 img.setAttribute('height',dimentions['height'])
```